# MongoDB Drive linq not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am relatively new to MongoDB and have found myself much more comfortable writing linq to extract data but when I tried this:

```
       var fieldList = await collection.AsQueryable<Change>()
                       .Where(f => f.Area == area && f.AreaRecordId == id)
                       .GroupBy(f => f.Field)
                       .Select(f => f.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateChange).FirstOrDefault())
                       .ToListAsync();
```

I got the error:
System.NotSupportedException: FirstOrDefault of type System.Linq.Enumerable is not supported in the expression tree { document}.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateChange).FirstOrDefault().

I understand that not every area of linq is supported.

My MongoDB stores documents of changes. Each change has among other things, an area, an area record id, field id and a date change property. For an area of specific record id, I want to be able to pull all the field changes (i.e. group by field id) but only the most recent ones.

Any thoughts how I could accomplish this? I did try with a more native MongoDB approach but got stuck straight away.

Comment: yeah mongo driver doesn't do so well with complex linq queries. you should invest some time into learning plain mongo aggregation queries if you want to do more than just the basic stuff supported by the driver and tie those aggregation queries to c# with something like [this](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110) or hand the json strings to the driver.